# Приложение с таймером на Android

Tags: android

Имеется код маленькой игры, в которой пользователь должен нажимать на правильную кнопку, после нажатия генерируется новое задание.

**Необходимо** чтобы пользователю давалось только определённое количество времени на то, чтобы отвечать на вопросы (При неправильном ответе время уменьшается).

Распишите пожалуйста подробно, пытался читать англоязычную документацию класса Timer, понял очень мало.

Comment: Создайте хэндлер который будет каждую секунду отнимать у переменной единицу. Чтобы уменьшить время уменьшите переменную. Запускайте хендлер при старте игры

Comment: Данный вариант не подходит, тк мне нужно чтобы была шкала времени в активности.

Comment: Не понял. Причем тут это? Я в своем плеере так каждую секунду счетчик проигрывания обновляю, проблем нет